# Forms are posting nothing when using SSL

Tags: php, security, ssl, joomla, https

When using JOOMLA site with SSL enabled all the forms on the website are Posting nothing!

`print_r($_POST);` results `null`

Please let me know how to get back all the Forms posting data as normal **even if SSL enabled**.

Comment: Can you post some code? There is no technical reason why it shouldn't.

Comment: This would only be true if you had a redirect happening in which case all post data would be lost.

Comment: I'm using Joomla's default SSL security and it is causing this problem. @Augwa Does Joomla's default SSL security  redirects pages and returns nothing in POST data?

Comment: When you're posting the form, is it over HTTPS or HTTP?

Comment: @cjhill There is no need to post code. If you do a test with form having a single input, it will also not work.

Comment: @Augwa There is a login form module on each page. Website has a payment page which loads with SSL enabled and other pages loads with SSL disabled. The login form on SSL enabled pages does not work and on SSL disabled pages, it works!

Comment: Is there a problem with the CSRF protection? I would check your cookie settings and make sure you're using SSL on every page.

Comment: I dont think so. Please note that SSL is enabled only on payment pages of my site.

Comment: That might be the problem, then.